# Divide certain elements in each sub list

Tags: python-3.x

```
b = [[2021, 55, -0.65, 7.61, 10.65, 41.37, 3.39, 12.25, -10.14, 7.61, 8.84],
     [2022, 56, 3.0, -0.13, 8.84, 27.25, -0.48, 2.54, 12.43, 7.56, 3.37]]
```

I want to divide elements [2:10] of each sub list in b by 100. Result expected:

```
a = [2021, 55, -0.0065, 0.0761, 0.1065, 0.4137, 0.0339, 0.1225, -0.1014, 0.0761, 0.0884], etc
```

I've tried:

```
a = [item[2:10] /100 for item in b] Also tried: a = [item[2:10] / 100 for item in x] for x in b]
```

The first one gives "unsupported operand type for /: list and int". Second one gives "int object not subscriptable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor error in your list comprehension, you were slicing in the wrong place. What you need to do is this:

```
a = [x[:2] + [item / 100 for item in x[2:]] for x in b]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[2021, 55, -0.006500000000000001, 0.0761, 0.1065, 0.41369999999999996, 0.0339, 0.1225, -0.1014, 0.0761, 0.08839999999999999], [2022, 56, 0.03, -0.0013, 0.08839999999999999, 0.2725, -0.0048, 0.0254, 0.1243, 0.0756, 0.0337]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without list comprehension

```
In [12]: b = [[2021, 55, -0.65, 7.61, 10.65, 41.37, 3.39, 12.25, -10.14, 7.61, 8
    ...: .84],
    ...:      [2022, 56, 3.0, -0.13, 8.84, 27.25, -0.48, 2.54, 12.43, 7.56, 3.37
    ...: ]]
    ...:

In [13]: for i in range(len(b)):
    ...:     if len(b[i]) >= 10:
    ...:         for j in range(2,10):
    ...:             b[i][j] = b[i][j]/100
```

output:

```
[[2021,
  55,
  -0.006500000000000001,
  0.0761,
  0.1065,
  0.41369999999999996,
  0.0339,
  0.1225,
  -0.1014,
  0.0761,
  8.84],
 [2022,
  56,
  0.03,
  -0.0013,
  0.08839999999999999,
  0.2725,
  -0.0048,
  0.0254,
  0.1243,
  0.0756,
  3.37]]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to take slices out first... change your list-comprehension to:

```
b = [[2021, 55, -0.65, 7.61, 10.65, 41.37, 3.39, 12.25, -10.14, 7.61, 8.84],
     [2022, 56, 3.0, -0.13, 8.84, 27.25, -0.48, 2.54, 12.43, 7.56, 3.37]]

res = [[item / 100 if 2 <= i < 10 else item for i, item in enumerate(lst)] for lst in b]

print(res)
```

Output:

`[[2021, 55, -0.006500000000000001, 0.0761, 0.1065, 0.41369999999999996, 0.0339, 0.1225, -0.1014, 0.0761, 8.84], [2022, 56, 0.03, -0.0013, 0.08839999999999999, 0.2725, -0.0048, 0.0254, 0.1243, 0.0756, 3.37]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
res = [x[:2] + [x[i]/100 for i in range(len(x)) if i > 1] for x in b]\
print(res)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.